# Can I call GORM "find" methods on an object instead of the class?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm trying to take advantage of the fact that groovy is more dynamic than java.
I'd like to have a block of code that does

```
TypeA type = //do something to build an object
TypeA dbType = TypeA.findBySomethingAndSomething(something, somethingelse)
if(dbType != null)
   type.id = dbType.id
type.save()
```

but that can work for multiple objects that support the same findBySomethingAndSomething method.

Is it possible to say

```
def type = //do something to build an object
def dbType = type.findBySomethingAndSomething(type.identifier, type.otheridentifier)
if(dbType != null)
   type.id = dbType.id
type.save()
```

Is there a "better" way to accomplish this?
I'm trying to avoid a large switch statement or if / else series that does essentially the same thing for each type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always get the class object from an instance via `instance.getClass()`. Therefore the following should work:

```
instance.getClass().findBySomethingAndSomething(type.identifier, type.otheridentifier)
```

as long as the instance's class supports `findBySomethingAndSomething`

Comment: Consider using getClass() instead. Won't make much difference in this case - but it's a good habit to get into in case 'instance' is ever a Map.

Comment: Good advice John, this has caught me out a few times when tests pass a map to mock an instance - I've updated my response.